# How to include a picture in a blog post such that it will show in Facebook?

Tags: images

- Worpress Blog: 3.9
- Theme: Twenty Eleven ( as a child theme )
- Blog: http://beforewisdom.com

I am using a wordpress.org blog.

It used to be that if I put an image or video at the top of my blog posts that image would appear on Facebook if I posted a URL of that blog post.

No more.

Any idea of what I can change in how I create my blog posts to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add meta data, embedded between the `<head>` tags in the html of your blog post, to tell Facebook exactly what information to show when that content is shared.

Here are the main meta tags Facebook uses:

```
<!-- Facebook Open Graph meta data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Here" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description Here" />
```

You'd simply add the link to the image from the blog post to the `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />` tag to tell Facebook which image to use.

Though as you are most likely not going to be editing the html code for each page yourself, you can use a plugin to add this information instead. I can recommend [Yoast SEO](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/), which also gives options for optimising a whole host of SEO settings for your site, however if you just want to add Facebook meta data you could try something like [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/) – though I haven't used it myself, the reviews seem reasonable. Google 'Facebook Meta Wordpress Plugin' for alternative options.

Comment: I'm just a personal, non monetary blogger wanting something simple.  I searched on the name for the second plugin from inside of worpress and found one that does only what I want.  It worked. "Fedmich's Facebook Open Graph Meta"  Thanks!